# Где сохраняются данные WebSQL?

Tags: websqldatabase

Есть цель сохранить связной список, содержащий данные о пользователе и изменять его. Думаю использовать WebSQL. Возникает вопрос: "Данные в WebSQL сохраняются на сайте в целом или как с localstorage (на устройстве) ?"

Comment: В конкретном браузере локально на устройстве. WebSQL устарел и на его место пришла indexDB.

Comment: @SwaD , расскажи про indexDB. Ну по крайней мере вопрос тот же остается

Comment: Ответ такой же - данные хранятся в конкретном браузере локально на устройстве пользователя. [IndexDB](https://learn.javascript.ru/indexeddb)

Comment: @SwaD, понял, спасибо

Comment: Используйте серверные БД для хранения инфы пользователя. MySql, postgree, SQlite, MongoDB

Comment: @SwaD, для записи данных пользователя я использую Firebase, функция уже написана. Мне нужно где-то собрать всю инфу только определенной сущности, изменять эти данные и получать. Я использовал связной список по понятным причинам (отсортированный массив на 100 человек будет очень долго записываться в памяти), а связной как раз подходит. Ничего лучше этого пока не придумал. У меня в профиле вопрос открыт как раз на эту тему